# Is point inside the bounds of a rotated uiview

Tags: iphone, rotation, bounds

I'm developing an iphone app.
I need to know if a given point on the screen is inside the area of the bounds of a rotated uiview. it's pretty clear how to do it based on the frame of the uiview but not on the bounds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
BOOL isInside = [view pointInside:point withEvent:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks!  should the point be in the coordination points of the view of the view's parents?

Comment: No worries! I think should be in reference to the `UIWindow`.

Comment: So I checked and it works good when the point is in the coordinates of the view. That makes sense as this is a uiview method, so it refers to itself.

Comment: You're quite right. Apologies, I should have checked Apple's docs which states: 'true if point is inside the receiver’s bounds; otherwise, false.'